# Why does the "Walk" state stop when the "Gun" state runs in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I spent hours trying to solve this problem: when I run the game, the character is moving correctly to the right and left, but when pulling the gun happens, the character never moves for some reason.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WalkParent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator = null;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(7f * dirX, rb.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 7f);
        }
        if (dirX > 0 || dirX < 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        }
        if (dirX == 0)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("pull");
        }
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("nopull");


        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I trigger the "Gun" animation with `animator.SetTrigger("pull");` and it's just pulling the gun animation.

This is how the problem looks:

[image]

I thought it'd be easier to connect "Any State" to "Gun." But what I had tried for the first time was using "Bool" for all of the animations and then connecting them together without using "Any State," and the problem still happened. I don't know if it's because "Gun" and "Walk" have the same keyframes for bones, so that creates this problem for me.

Comment: i believe its becasue its all one layer, so only 1 state is active

Comment: @BugFinder At first read, I thought you were talking about the layers in the hierarchy tab, not the animator tab. So I solved the problem. Thank you. Should I delete the question now?

Comment: Na. I will write it up and you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animator can only have 1 active state on a given layer. As a result despite looking like two separate unrelated choices on your screen. It will only allow you to pick one

If you move one of the two to a new layer it can do its own thing